# Azure Blob copy folder from one container to another after zipping it

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

Inside a blob storage I have two containers `Source` and `Target`. I need to copy the folders from `Source` to `target` but one condition is that the folders need to be zipped before I copy them into the `Target` container. I am using Python. I have managed to copy the folders but I haven't been able to find a way to zip them.

```
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(account_url='https://blob_storage.blob.core.windows.net/',credential='access_key')

source_container_name = "Source"
source_file_path = "1644579641903/data_0_0_0.csv"

source_blob = f"https://blob_storage.blob.core.windows.net/{source_container_name}/{source_file_path}"

target_container_name = "Target"
target_file_path = "1644579641903/data_0_0_0.csv"

copied_blob = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(target_container_name, target_file_path)
copied_blob.start_copy_from_url(source_blob)
```

Comment: Do you need to zip BEFORE you transfer (as in, a zipped version will remain in Source) or do you want to zip in flight (so only Target has a zipped version)? Also, is Python a requirement or can you use Azure Data Factory?

Comment: Any thing works zip before transfer or zip in flight and I can use Azure Data Factory as well.

Comment: Data factory Copy activity makes this really easy. Just have a binary dataset (source) with no compression and a binary dataset (target) with ZipDeflate compression. Copy will zip the file in flight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested in my environment

As suggested by [Joel Cochran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/75838/joel-cochran), we can use Copy Activity in Azure Data Factory to copy the folder from one container to another container after zipping it

You need to create a Linked service with your Azure Blob Storage account details in Azure Data Factory

Create a pipeline with Copy Data Activity. Select Source as Azure Blob Storage binary dataset with source container and compression type as None

Select Sink as Azure Blob Storage binary dataset with your target container and compression type as **ZipDeflate**

Publish and Run the Pipeline. A zip file with all the files and folders in source container will be  copied to the target container